# Import template from separate html file in polymer 3

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, es6-modules, polymer-3.x

Instead of `return "HTML CONTENT";` I have a separate html file and I want to import it to my js file to return the content of it but `import template from '/m-chip.html";` does not work.

element.js

```
import {Element as PolymerElement} from '../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import template from '/m-chip.html';
export class Mchip extends PolymerElement{
    static get template() {
        return template;
    } 
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
} 
customElements.define("m-chip" ,Mchip)
```

m-chip.html

```
<style>
...
</style>

<div>...</div>
```

How can I achieve this without jquery and plain js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well importing html files is not something that javascript will understand at the moment. However you can build your project with webpack and add html-loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader that specify how to treat your html import inside javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Actually for html where you don't need the reference adjusting, i export the html code as a string through the js module export default :

```
// exports a constant 
export default `
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
  <div>
    ...
  </div> `
```

And in the polymer element i import the ES6 module eg:

```
import template from '../templates/template.js'
...
static get template() {
  return template;
}
```

It's not the best solution, but for the moment to made some tests with Polymer3 and templating structuring is not so bad !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer';
import template from '/m-chip.html';
```

...

```
static get template() { 
    return html([template]);
}
```

and just plain html in the template html file, that works for me.

Comment: It doesn't look like this works natively without the use of additional libraries. Chrome throws a MIME type error.

Comment: You definitely need a transpiler like Webpack to be able to pull this off.